# How to use CalcBinding in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, calcbinding

I have two text boxes `Quantity` and `PricePerItem` and a TextBlock named as `TotalTb`. What i want is multiply Quantity with PricePerItem and reflect result in TextBlock using [CalcBinding](https://github.com/Alex141/CalcBinding).
Will i've to create respective properties at backend ? or Apply INotifyPropertyChanged for simple calculations like this ?
Not using MVVM. What's the simplest way to achieve this ?

```
<TextBox x:Name="Quantity"/>
<TextBox x:Name="PricePerItem"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="TotalTb"/>
```

Comment: 1) winforms-way: subscribe to `TextChanged` event of input fields, calculate and set new value for result field 2) correct way: bind everything, in input field property setters rise notification for getter-only property which return result of calculation.

Comment: @Sinatr i already that know that way. Even in WPF it's same but i don't want that. I want calculations in binding ...

Comment: *"I want calculations in binding"* - what stops you? You found a library and there are examples. Can you rather show your attempt?

Comment: @Sinatr sir i have no idea how there examples are even working . There is text="{Cal:Binding A+B+C"} now from where A B and C came ? i literally have now idea ..

Comment: "Will i've to create respective properties at backend ? or Apply INotifyPropertyChanged for simple calculations like this ?" and "Not using MVVM" and "the simplest way to achieve this" contradict each other

Comment: `"{Cal:Binding A+B+C}"` - here you have to [map in xaml namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/630468/1997232) `Cal`,  it's custom class `CalcBinding.Binding` (or something), where `"A+B+C"` its constructor parameter. Those are probably just property names combined into expression. So yes, you have to define properties and start using normal bindings first. Yes, you rise notifications for those properties when they change (typically in setters). Don't be scared of MVVM, you have to set `DataContext` for binding to work and MVVM is simply all about organizing that.

Comment: @Sinatr Sir i do know about namespaces. And what is CalcBinding or Calc or just C.Binding . What i am not understanding is A+B+C. Please forvive me but i am not pro and just trying to understand. If i've to work with backend properties and INotify and set some Value for third box from backed (obviously there i can also do some calculation and assign value ) then what this library is doing ?

Comment: @ASh sir i know maybe my statements are contradicting but i still believe there must be some simple and easier way for noobs like me. And i do understand how to handle this from back end but i am just thinking this way i can also just do calculations from backend and assign ..but then where is ease these libs (particularly this) is providing ?

Comment: @Hammas, contradicting requirements make any task impossible, no solution exists

Comment: @ASh there is always a solution . Ill find no problem thanks :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734960/which-are-practically-unsolvable-problems-in-programming-world, [List of unsolved problems in computer science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_computer_science). the presented case is different, but still

Comment: @Hammas cannot use [calcbinding](https://github.com/Alex141/CalcBinding/issues/40) for multiple 'ElementName' properties. Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661493/elegant-solution-for-readonly-values/15663083#15663083